# mysql pivot/crosstab query

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

**Question 1:** I have a table with the below structure and data:

```
app_id  transaction_id  mobile_no   node_id  customer_attribute  entered_value 
100     111             9999999999  1        Q1                  2                             
100     111             9999999999  2        Q2                  1                             
100     111             9999999999  3        Q3                  4                             
100     111             9999999999  4        Q4                  3                             
100     111             9999999999  5        Q5                  2                             
100     222             8888888888  4        Q4                  1                             
100     222             8888888888  3        Q3                  2                             
100     222             8888888888  2        Q2                  1                             
100     222             8888888888  1        Q1                  3                             
100     222             8888888888  5        Q5                  4
```

I want to display these records in the below format:

```
app_id  |  transaction_id  | mobile     |  Q1  |  Q2  |  Q3  |  Q4 |  Q5  |
 100    |      111         | 9999999999 |   2  |   1  |   4  |  3  |  2   |
 100    |      222         | 8888888888 |   3  |   1  |   2  |  1  |  4   |
```

I know I need to use crosstab/pivot query to get this display. For this I tried it based on the limited knowledge that I have about it. Following is my query:

```
SELECT app_id, transaction_id, mobile_no,
  (CASE node_id WHEN 1 THEN entered_value ELSE '' END) AS user_input1,
  (CASE node_id WHEN 2 THEN entered_value ELSE '' END) AS user_input2,
  (CASE node_id WHEN 3 THEN entered_value ELSE '' END) AS user_input3,
  (CASE node_id WHEN 4 THEN entered_value ELSE '' END) AS user_input4,
  (CASE node_id WHEN 5 THEN entered_value ELSE '' END) AS user_input5
FROM trn_user_log 
GROUP BY app_id, transaction_id, mobile_no, node_id
```

And based on this query I got the below display:

```
app_id  transaction_id  mobile_no   user_input1  user_input2  user_input3  user_input4  user_input5  
100     111             9999999999  2                                                                
100     111             9999999999               1                                                   
100     111             9999999999                            4                                      
100     111             9999999999                                         3                         
100     111             9999999999                                                      2            
100     222             8888888888  3                                                                
100     222             8888888888               1                                                   
100     222             8888888888                            2                                      
100     222             8888888888                                         1                         
100     222             8888888888                                                      4
```

Can anyone help me with the proper changes that I need to make to my query to get the records in one single row and not multiple rows as above.

**Question 2:** Also is there a way to get the value of a particular field as the NAME of the column. As you can see above I have `user_input1`, `user_input2`,... as the header. Instead of that I want to have the values in `customer_attribute` as the header of the columns.

For this I checked `NAME_CONST(name,value)` as below:

```
SELECT app_id, transaction_id, mobile_no,
NAME_CONST(customer_attribute, (CASE node_id WHEN 1 THEN entered_value ELSE '' END))
FROM trn_user_log
```

But it gives an error

```
Error Code : 1210 Incorrect arguments to NAME_CONST
```

Help required.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While @John's static answer works great, if you have an unknown number of columns that you want to transform, I would consider using prepared statements to get the results:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'GROUP_CONCAT((CASE node_id when ',
      node_id,
      ' then entered_value else NULL END)) AS user_input',
      node_id
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM trn_user_log;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT app_id, transaction_id, mobile_no, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM trn_user_log 
                  GROUP BY app_id, transaction_id, mobile_no');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cbde/29)

As far as your second, please clarify what you are trying to do it is not clear.

Comment: man!! you read my mind... that's exactly what I wanted and I was doing.. I was writing a stored proc to do the exact same thing. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Gaurav no problem, I don't fully understand your second question though.

Comment: yeah thats very tricky.. and I doubt that would be even possible writing in an SQL. I want the value of a column say `customer_attr` to be diplayed as the header in place of `user_input`. So for example `Q1` should be displayed in place of `user_input1`. I know I can handle this thing in the java code by getting the header columns separately and displaying it likewise. But I was just wondering if such a thing is possible or not. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible I tested it but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 9):

Add `GROUP_CONCAT` in your `CASE` clause

```
SELECT app_id, transaction_id, mobile_no,
  GROUP_CONCAT((CASE node_id WHEN 1 THEN entered_value ELSE NULL END)) AS user_input1,
  GROUP_CONCAT((CASE node_id WHEN 2 THEN entered_value ELSE NULL END)) AS user_input2,
  GROUP_CONCAT((CASE node_id WHEN 3 THEN entered_value ELSE NULL END)) AS user_input3,
  GROUP_CONCAT((CASE node_id WHEN 4 THEN entered_value ELSE NULL END)) AS user_input4,
  GROUP_CONCAT((CASE node_id WHEN 5 THEN entered_value ELSE NULL END)) AS user_input5
FROM trn_user_log 
GROUP BY app_id, transaction_id, mobile_no
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cbde/4)

Comment: @Gaurav why did in the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cbde/4) work? remove `node_id` in your group by clause

Comment: Excellent! it worked now. Forgot to remove `node_id` from the groupby. Do you have the answer to my second question? display value of `customer_attribute` in place of `user_inputx`?

Comment: @Gaurav sorry i can't help you with that, it seems your converting the record to the name of the column.

Answer (score 4):

@DarkKnightFan, this was a very helpful question for a task I was working. I went ahead and modified the solution from @bluefin to solve your second question.  The following code produces your originally requested format with the value of customer_attribute as the resulting column headings in the cross-tab.

The relevant change was to change:

```
' then entered_value else NULL END)) AS user_input',
      node_id
```

To this:

```
' then entered_value else NULL END)) AS ''',
          customer_attribute,''''
```

The full code:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'GROUP_CONCAT((CASE node_id when ',
      node_id,
      ' then entered_value else NULL END)) AS ''',
      customer_attribute,''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM trn_user_log;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT app_id, transaction_id, mobile_no, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM trn_user_log 
                  GROUP BY app_id, transaction_id, mobile_no');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Also, for other users browsing this issue, if you have a lot of values that you are trying to cross-tab, you may run into error because GROUP_CONCAT() has a default max length of 1024 characters. To increase put this at the start of your prepared statement:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = value; -- replace value with an int
```