# Multiple rows in a single one in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql pivot/crosstab query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382771/mysql-pivot-crosstab-query)

I'm using MySQL and PHP, I have this table from a JOIN query......

```
╔═══════╦════════════════╦═══════════════╦════════╗
║ name  ║    last_name   ║ course_name   ║ tries  ║
╠═══════╬════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╣
║ coco  ║ valencia       ║ Course Num. 1 ║     11 ║
║ coco  ║ valencia       ║ Course Num. 2 ║     10 ║
║ coco  ║ valencia       ║ Course Num. 3 ║      4 ║
║ coco  ║ valencia       ║ Course Num. 4 ║      5 ║
║ John  ║ Smith          ║ Course Num. 1 ║      7 ║
║ John  ║ Smith          ║ Course Num. 2 ║      6 ║
╚═══════╩════════════════╩═══════════════╩════════╝
```

And I want my table result as this......

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ name  ║ last_name ║ Course Num.1 ║ Course Num. 2 ║ Course Num. 3 ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ coco  ║ valencia  ║           11 ║            10 ║             4 ║
║ John  ║ Smith     ║            7 ║             6 ║               ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

I've been searching and can't find a way to do it.  The solution can be in PHP or MySQL or both.

Comment: it's possible, but the query is VERY ugly if you go mysql-only. you're better off doing a normal select and transforming in PHP.

Comment: Are there only 4 courses, or an unlimited number?

Comment: @kastulo Then indeed it is ugly.  It must be done by constructing a dynamic SQL statement to account for all possible courses.

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382771/mysql-pivot-crosstab-query

Comment: What is the basis on which you chose to ignore Coco's registration for Course Num. 4?  (Nice use of the box drawing characters, by the way.)

Comment: actually I don't ignore it, I just outputted 3 courses because of space, sorry if that's misleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  name, last_Name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN course_name = 'Course Num. 1' THEN tries ELSE NULL END) `Course Num. 1`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN course_name = 'Course Num. 2' THEN tries ELSE NULL END) `Course Num. 2`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN course_name = 'Course Num. 3' THEN tries ELSE NULL END) `Course Num. 3`
FROM    tableName
GROUP BY name, last_Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b9f8/3)

if you have unknown number of `Course_Name`, *PreparedStatement* is what you need,

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN course_name =  ''',
      course_name,
      ''' then tries ELSE NULL end) AS ''',
      course_name, ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tableName;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  name, last_Name, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM    tableName
                   GROUP BY name, last_Name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b9f8/6)

Comment: Half the statement you put I dont understand, but it works, thanks a ton, im gonna get into procedural a lot more.

Comment: the second one is the dynamic sql statement.