# MySQL multiple values with group and sum

Tags: mysql

I have table like this :

```
ID    CHANNEL  PRODUCT  VNAME         qty
1     MCN      zynga    zynga v10     100
2     AGN      zynga    zynga v10     100
3     WAR      zynga    zynga v10     200
4     WWW      zynga    zynga v10     250
5     MCN      capple   capple v52    700
6     AGN      capple   capple v52    100
7     WAR      capple   capple v52    200
8     MCN      zynga    zynga v21     50
9     AGN      zynga    zynga v21     30
10    WAR      zynga    zynga v21     20
```

I need query to produce result like this :

```
ID    PRODUCT    MCN    AGN    WAR   WWW
1     zynga      150    139    220   270
2     capple     700    100    200   0
```

Note: MCN, AGN, WAR, WWW value is from sum of qty value

Comment: How are the ID values in your required result derived?

Comment: see if this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382771/mysql-pivot-crosstab-query

Comment: @nurdglaw ID in result data is no need actually

Answer (score -1):

This problem can be solved with aggregate functions and specifically the combination of SUM(IF()) functions in addition to using group by with product.

### Dynamic Approach using Prepared Statement

Thanks to comment from AshReva linking to [mysql pivot/crosstab query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382771/mysql-pivot-crosstab-query)

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(IF(CHANNEL="',
      channel,
      '",qty,0)) as ',
      channel
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM prod;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT product, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM prod 
                  GROUP BY product');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed185/5

### Non-dynamic way of solving this...

```
select PRODUCT, 
SUM(IF(CHANNEL="MCN", qty, 0)) as MCN,
SUM(IF(CHANNEL="AGN", qty, 0)) as AGN,
etc...
from PRODUCTS
GROUP by PRODUCT;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed185/2