# Designing an application but can I Create new MySQL fields while the application is running?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

## What I Have:

I have already designed, and am successfully running a VBA based excel spreadsheet that creates an "Action Plan" for the user.

Basically, you create a number of tasks and each time you add an update there is a new Column added with the days date in. This will then hold the new update for the action on the row you are appending to. Each action could have an update or it may be only one.

Each update will require it's own Cell in a new Column with the day's date as a header.

## What I want:

I want to create this as a stand alone application that I can roll out and my first thoughts are to design it in C# using Visual Studio and use a database held in MySQL.

## Example Image:

[image: Example of action plan]

## My Question:

As you can see, each day held an update. However, would holding all of this information in this way be best done in a database?

If not, can it be held in another way but still displayed like this? Perhaps using arrays?

I guess my question is more if the MySQL database will allow C# to create new fields(Headers) with the day's date as a title while the application is running?

Please keep in mind that I am VERY new to programming in general but even more so in C# and using MySQL so sorry if this seems to be a very "Easy" or "Stupid" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to add the fields within C# (ALTER TABLE),
I would stay away from this, a better approach might be a relational database

For example

TableA

```
[Ref]|[Action]|[Reason]              |[Assignee]|[Due Date]
1    |Test    |For Better Explanation|          |16/04/2014
```

TableB

```
[ID]|[Ref]|[Date]    |[Action]
1   |1    |06/04/2014|
2   |1    |07/04/2014|
3   |1    |08/04/2014|
```

The link will be TableB.Ref = TableA.Ref

Therefor you will know that the entries in TableB belongs to a specific entry in TableA

Then in C# you can first populate a spreadsheet with all data from TableA
And then from TableB.

You can also take a look at crosstab queries ([mysql pivot/crosstab query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382771/mysql-pivot-crosstab-query))

Comment: I had never even considered the linking of tables. But as I did say, I am very new to database way of working.

Comment: no worries, we all started somewhere and had some kind of problem. shout if you need any other help

Comment: I'm sure there will be plenty more to come as I will now have to learn how to Normalise and create a relational database.

Answer (score 3):

You really should not update database schema (add new columns to tables) after you initially create them (atleast without good reason). You also might want to read up on database normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

You most likely want to create another table where each date is a row.

```
| ref | action_id | date       | title          |
| 1   |         1 | 06/04/2014 | NEW ACTION     |
| 2   |         1 | 07/04/2014 | One update     |
| 3   |         2 | 07/04/2014 | Another action |
```

.. and so on.