# PHP & MySQL, laying out in CSV format with special parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, csv

I have a database that has budgets in them (for this, I have modified the budgets to be fake).

Long story short, I am attempting to run the following SQL query on the database, and then display a report based on it.

Here is the query: `SELECT MONTHNAME(date) AS month, product, SUM(amount) AS spend FROM client_budgets WHERE advertiser_id = '$advertiser_id' GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date), product ORDER BY MONTH(date) ASC`

I then clean the data a little, here is the code for that:

```
foreach($data AS $key => $val) {
    $clean_data[] = $val;
}
```

From this, I get the following (this is a PHP array of the data. I have cut it off since it has about 100K rows in the database currently).

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => January
            [product] => Internet
            [spend] => 12000.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => January
            [product] => Radio
            [spend] => 12250.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => February
            [product] => Billboards
            [spend] => 6000.00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => February
            [product] => Internet
            [spend] => 16000.00
        )
)
```

My goal is to end up being able to display in a CSV (I already have the headers set for the CSV), the following:

```
Month, Internet, Radio, Billboards, Television
January, 12000, 12250, 6000, 0
February, 16000, 7000, 6000, 2000
....
```

I am stuck right now trying to sort the data correctly, and if there is no data for Television for instance one month, to display a 0.  Any help would be appreciated! I have been attempting this for almost 3 days now.

Comment: This would be *much* easier (or at least, easier to do at the database level and IMO would produce a generally better data format) if you you transpose the data, so that the months are the columns and the products are the rows... Each time you add a product, you add a column. In general it's better to have a data structure with many rows and few columns rather than the other way round.

Comment: So, for instance, in the database, each row looks like the following:
`id, advertiser, date, number, product, description, amount`

`1, ppjb39k, 2014-02-12, 2056, Billboards, Phoenix Digital Billboards - January 2014, 6000.0`

Just move the rows around so how it works is that each row is a product?  The problem with that is I also need the database to be able to hold multiple clients.  Are you able to set up something on http://sqlfiddle.com/ so I can see what you mean?  I am setting one up right now for my database

Comment: I have created a small version of the database on sqlfiddle.com.  Take a look, and if you have any suggestions, I am open at this point.  It is being a pain to do this, and we are adding new products every month now, so it is getting to be a pain updating all the code. Here is my SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0099/2

Comment: [Database abuse](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a830b/1)

Comment: MySQL does not provide built-in support for pivot queries, but there are ways to work around it. You can do it, obviously, in PHP... or even in MySQL. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382771/mysql-pivot-crosstab-query