# join 3 tables with 1 of the tables rows becoming columns

Tags: mysql, database

I'll try to explain my goal as best I can:

3 tables -

select * from users;

```
+--------+----------+
|   id   | firstname|
+--------+----------+
|    1   |  John    |    
|    2   |  Mary    |
+--------+----------+
```

select * from links;

```
+--------+---------+-----------------+
|user_id | link_id | viewname        |
+--------+---------+-----------------+
|   1    |   11    | John and Jane   |
|   2    |   13    | Mary and Mike   |
+--------+---------+-----------------+
```

select * from values;

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
|link_id |value_id  |link_value |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|   11   |   2      |  Image1   |
|   11   |   5      |  Steak    |
|   13   |   5      |  Chicken  |
|   11   |   3      |  Blue     |
|   11   |   4      |  Option1  |
|   13   |   1      |  Yes      |
|   13   |   2      |  Image2   |
|   13   |   4      |  Option1  |
|   13   |   3      |  Green    |
|   11   |   1      |  No       |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

My goal is to join the three tables and make the contents of value_id a column header. Like this-

```
+------------+---------------+------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| firstname  |    viewname   |   1  |   2    |    3    |   4     |   5     |    
+------------+---------------+------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|   John     | John and Jane |  No  | Image1 |   Blue  | Option1 | Steak   |
|   Mary     | Mike and Mary |  Yes | Image2 |   Green | Option1 | Chicken |
+------------+---------------+------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

[MySQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6178b)

I have tried and tried and failed. Any help/suggestions at this point would be appreciated.

Comment: What you are asking for is called Pivoting. In particular, you would like to pivot the value_id column in the values table.

Comment: Pivot/crosstab query. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382771/mysql-pivot-crosstab-query)

Comment: Note that issues of data display are generally best resolved in the presentation layer/application level code, assuming that's available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this sample data, you can try following query;)

```
select 
    u.firstname, l.viewname,
    max(if(lv.value_id = 1, lv.`value`, '')) as `1`,
    max(if(lv.value_id = 2, lv.`value`, '')) as `2`,
    max(if(lv.value_id = 3, lv.`value`, '')) as `3`,
    max(if(lv.value_id = 4, lv.`value`, '')) as `4`,
    max(if(lv.value_id = 5, lv.`value`, '')) as `5`
from users u
inner join links l
on u.`id` = l.`user_id`
inner join link_value lv
on l.link_id = lv.link_id
group by u.firstname, l.viewname
```

## SQLFiddle Demo

And if you have a dynamic values for `value_id`, you have to create a dynamic sql to do this, like:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(lv.value_id = ',
      value_id,
      ', lv.`value`, '''')) AS `',
      value_id, '`'
    ) ORDER BY value_id
  ) INTO @sql
FROM link_value
;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT u.firstname, l.viewname, ', @sql,
                  ' FROM users u
                   INNER JOIN links l
                   ON u.`id` = l.`user_id`
                   INNER JOIN link_value lv
                   ON l.link_id = lv.link_id
                   GROUP BY u.firstname, l.viewname');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

## SQLFiddle Demo

Comment: This worked perfectly, and is almost exactly what I had been trying, but I had missed some single quotes.-Any idea why this does not work in phpMyAdmin?