# SQL adding new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I would be happy to ask my first question on StackOverflow.
I have two tables (employees and salaries) within my database (employees).

Employees table looks like this:

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no     | int           | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(14)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(16)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Salaries table looks like this:

```
+-----------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no    | int  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| salary    | int  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| from_date | date | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| to_date   | date | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to return values for a specific date interval. For instance, I want to know what salary an employee had for an interval in a dynamic view, for the 1990-1991 years for 1991-1992 years, etc.

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT 
    e.emp_no,
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    s.salary AS Salary_for_1990
FROM
    employees e
        JOIN
    salaries s ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no
WHERE
    from_date BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '1990-12-31'
GROUP BY e.emp_no
ORDER BY e.emp_no ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

I got the following result:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+-----------------+
| emp_no | first_name | last_name | Salary_for_1990 |
+--------+------------+-----------+-----------------+
|  10001 | Georgi     | Facello   |           66961 |
|  10004 | Christian  | Koblick   |           48271 |
|  10005 | Kyoichi    | Maliniak  |           82621 |
|  10006 | Anneke     | Preusig   |           40000 |
|  10007 | Tzvetan    | Zielinski |           60740 |
|  10009 | Sumant     | Peace     |           70889 |
|  10011 | Mary       | Sluis     |           42365 |
|  10013 | Eberhardt  | Terkki    |           46305 |
|  10018 | Kazuhide   | Peha      |           61648 |
|  10021 | Ramzi      | Erde      |           59700 |
+--------+------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

So it works for a single value '1990-1991' years, however, **I seek for a possibility to add in the query additional column for '1991-1992', '1992-1993' years, etc** to be able to see the dynamic growth of employee's salaries.
I thought about variables, however, I don't have an idea how to query it within the context.

Look forward to your answers.
 Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if an employee had a salary change on March 1st, 1991: what do you want to display for year 1991?

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: And how do you want to see the result of this new query

Comment: Your select/idea isn't correct. Imagine a senior employe who has same salary from year 1985 till now. He will not be in the result.

Comment: GMB I don't look for a precise result. Just observe its raw dynamics.

Comment: jarlh what would you suggest to do instead ?

Comment: RiggsFolly I wanna add new columns as a new interval for instance for 1994-1995 etc. And observe its dynamics

Comment: MichalSv As query shows the Senior employee will demonstrate the same salary or I didn't get you correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People have a salary *as of a date* not as of a range of dates.

For your problem, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN from_date <= '1990-01-01' AND to_date > '1990-01-01' THEN salary END) as salary_19900101,
       MAX(CASE WHEN from_date <= '1991-01-01' AND to_date > '1991-01-01' THEN salary END) as salary_19910101,
       MAX(CASE WHEN from_date <= '1992-01-01' AND to_date > '1991-02-01' THEN salary END) as salary_19910101
FROM employees e JOIN
     salaries s 
     ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no
GROUP BY e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name
ORDER BY e.emp_no ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Notes:

- This has the salary as of the first day of the year.  You can have the salary as of any particular day (say De 31 or Jul 1).
- If an employee has no salary for a particular year, the value is `NULL`.
- The `GROUP BY` clause has all the unaggregated columns.  Although this is not formally required if `emp_no` is the primary key, it is a good habit if you are learning SQL.

Answer (score 0):

One simple possibility are subqueries, although it's not very elegant and does not scale well with many years:

```
SELECT 
e.emp_no,
e.first_name,
e.last_name,
(SELECT s.salary FROM salaries s WHERE s.emp_no = e.emp_no AND from_date BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '1990-12-31') Salary_for_1990,
(SELECT s.salary FROM salaries s WHERE s.emp_no = e.emp_no AND from_date BETWEEN '1991-01-01' AND '1991-12-31') Salary_for_1991
...
```

Comment: Whats the point of giving `salaries` and alias of `s` and then not using it

Comment: Of course you're right. I fixed it. I'm not a big fan of aliases but added it to fit the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May you suggest me how to make it scalable in order to advance its usability?

Comment: I f scaling is needed, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382771/mysql-pivot-crosstab-query

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this 'scaleable' then you should use conditional aggregation and prepared statements for example

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(emp int,dt date,salary int);

insert into t values
(1,'2015-06-30',7),
(1,'2015-12-31',10),
(1,'2016-12-31',05),
(1,'2017-12-31',10),
(2,'2015-12-31',20),
(2,'2016-12-31',25),
(2,'2017-12-31',30);

set @sql =
        (select group_concat(concat('max(case when year(dt) = ',dt ,' then salary else 0 end) as ', 'yr',dt))
        from
        (
        select distinct year(dt) dt from t
        ) s
        )
;
set @sql = (select concat('Select emp,',@sql,' from t group by emp'));

prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;

+------+--------+--------+--------+
| emp  | yr2015 | yr2016 | yr2017 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
|    1 |     10 |      5 |     10 |
|    2 |     20 |     25 |     30 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note this will return the MAX salary in any given year.