# SQL merge several rows into Single row on matching value

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

what I am looking to do is merge several rows of data to be displayed as a single row.

FROM THIS:

| Contract ID | Contract group ID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 140 | 189 | 90.00 |
| 140 | 190 | 85.00 |
| 140 | 191 | 300.00 |
| 151 | 190 | 10.00 |
| 152 | 189 | 200.00 |
| 152 | 191 | 50.00 |

TO THIS:

| Contract ID | Group 189 | Group 190 | Group 191 | Total amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 140 | 90.00 | 85.00 | 300.00 | 475.00 |
| 151 | 00.00 | 10.00 | 00.00 | 10.00 |
| 152 | 200.00 | 00.00 | 50.00 | 50.00 |

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try a CROSSTAB query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql pivot/crosstab query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382771/mysql-pivot-crosstab-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select contractid,
    max(case when contractgroupid = 189 then amount else 0 end) as group_189,
    max(case when contractgroupid = 190 then amount else 0 end) as group_190,
    max(case when contractgroupid = 191 then amount else 0 end) as group_191,
    max(case when contractgroupid = 192 then amount else 0 end) as group_192,
    sum(amount) as total_amount
from mytable
group by contractid
```

If the same group may appear more than once for a given contract, you might want to use `sum()` instead of `max()`.