# Presenting MySQL data with multiple rows across multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following database schema in place:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cf981/5

`boxes` have `items` within them, which have a value. `users` own `boxes`. `users` can have multiple `boxes` in a single month.

I want to generate an output where I can show the user, their creation date, then each month between a certain period the total of all items in all of that users boxes, such as this:

| user_id | user_created | 2019-July | 2019-August | 2019-September | 2019-October | 2019-November | 2019-December |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-21T01:12:53Z | 55 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 2021-01-21T01:12:53Z | 20 | 20 | 20 | 35.55 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 2021-01-21T01:12:53Z | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 29.99 |

What I've come up with so far is as follows, which outputs rows with non unique users or months.

```sql
SELECT
    u.id AS user_id,
    u.created AS user_created,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(b.creation_date, '%Y-%M') AS box_month,
    (
        SELECT SUM(amount) FROM items WHERE box_id = b.id
    ) AS total
FROM
  users AS u,
  boxes AS b
WHERE
  u.id = b.user_id
AND
  b.creation_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Jul 01 2019 12:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')) 
 AND
  b.creation_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Jan 01 2021 12:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql pivot/crosstab query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382771/mysql-pivot-crosstab-query)

Comment: Recommend doing the basic query, and then use an application language to do formatting because they do it significantly easier than pivot tables.